# Set Key of a Dictionary to equal a property in a struct instance used as a Value

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

I am new to coding in general and I'm starting my journey with Swift; so feel free to ask for any clarifications if I failed to properly explain my self in what follows (And of course, many thanks in advance). Here is the story:

**Background:**

I have declared a struct where it has a constant property to be set upon instantiation to a unique ID Integer number.

In addition, I have declared a Dictionary where its Keys will be a unique ID Integer Number and the Values is an instance of the Structure previously declared. The unique ID Integer in the Dictionary Key should be equal to the ID Integer property in the struct instance added to the Dictionary as a Value.

Here is the code for clarification:

```
struct SampleStruct {
    let id: Int
    var title: String //this variable is irrelevant to the question
}

var sampleDictionary: [Int : sampleStructInstance] = [:]

sampleDictionary[1] = SampleStruct(id: 1, title: "Test text") 
// Dictionary Key 1 is equal to Value.id 1 

sampleDictionary[2] = SampleStruct(id: 2, title: "Test text")
// Dictionary Key 2 is equal to Value.id 2
```

**Question:**
How can I write the code so that the code accesses the struct instance, checks the ID number, and sets the Dictionary Key to that ID number when adding the struct instance as a value to that dictionary key?

Since I'm new to coding, there is nothing much to try although I have tried Googling my question which I have not been successful in finding its answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method which adds the struct to the dictionary accordingly

```
func addToSampleDictionary(sample: SampleStruct) {
    sampleDictionary[sample.id] = sample
}
```

and use it

```
let sample1 = SampleStruct(id: 1, title: "Test text")
addToSampleDictionary(sample: sample1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can extend the functionality of an existing type by adding methods or computed properties in an extension so we can do that there to `Dictionary`. When doing this you can also limit how the code in the extension can be used by adding a `where` condition.

So here is the extension where we say that the key must be a `Int` and that the value must be a `SampleStruct`

```
extension Dictionary where Key == Int, Value == SampleStruct
```

We can now add a function to this extension and make it specific to `SampleStruct`

extension Dictionary where Key == Int, Value == SampleStruct {
mutating func add(_ object: Value) {
self[object.id] = object
}
}

To use this function we can then do

```
var sampleDictionary: [Int : SampleStruct] = [:]
sampleDictionary.add(SampleStruct(id: 1, title: "Test text"))
sampleDictionary.add(SampleStruct(id: 2, title: "Test text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to ensure that the dictionary key and struct id match is to create a helper function for adding to the dictionary:

```
var sampleDictionary: [Int : SampleStruct] = [:]

func addSampleStruct(_ sampleStruct: SampleStruct) {
    sampleDictionary[sampleStruct.id] = sampleStruct
}

addSampleStruct(SampleStruct(id: 1, title: "Test text"))
addSampleStruct(SampleStruct(id: 2, title: "Test text"))
```

One way to ensure that the dictionary was never accessed directly, potentially adding a mismatched key and id, is to create a separate class or struct that has the dictionary and functions for adding/fetching etc:

```
struct SampleDictionary {
    private var dictionary: [Int: SampleStruct] = [:]
    
    mutating func add(_ sampleStruct: SampleStruct) {
        dictionary[sampleStruct.id] = sampleStruct
    }
    
    func sampleStruct(withId id: Int) -> SampleStruct? {
        dictionary[id]
    }
    
    mutating func removeSampleStruct(withId id: Int) {
        dictionary[id] = nil
    }
    
    var count: Int {
        dictionary.count
    }
}

var sampleDictionary = SampleDictionary()

sampleDictionary.add(SampleStruct(id: 1, title: "Test text"))
sampleDictionary.add(SampleStruct(id: 2, title: "Test text"))

print("count: \(sampleDictionary.count)")

for id in 1...3 {
    if let sampleStruct = sampleDictionary.sampleStruct(withId: id) {
    print("sampleStruct with id \(id) = \(sampleStruct)")
    } else {
        print("there is no sampleStruct with id \(id)")
    }
}
```